# Is it ok to delete old .apk after renaming the project?

Tags: android

I renamed the project successfully but now there seems to be having two **.apk** files. Do I have to keep the **old** .apk? . Currently my new .apk file has no errors. Will it corrupt later?. Or if I remove it will my project be still fine forever? I have a long term usage idea for this project so what is best to do.

But keeping the old **name.apk** is like keeping garbage I need a clean project... What can I do? And how this affects when I need to sell application in Android market.

Comment: Delete the old apk safely. There's no reason to keep it. It will only bloat your project /bin folder size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the old **.apk** file, it only because you rename your project, so it generates a different file.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play (Android Market) will see it as a new app if you change the package name.

If you haven't already uploaded the original version, yes, you can just delete your local `.apk`.

Answer (score 0):

delete `bin` and `gen` folder to clean up with old built data.it will be built again automatically if you have checked true in front of `Build automatically` option in `Project` tab.

Comment: are you really sure about this?

Comment: @Shashi: Yes, Damn sure.